# Libgdx Box2D - Draw Sprite on Body - Heavy problems

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, sprite, physics

I'm heaving heavy problems with drawing a Sprite on a Box2D body.

I'm creating a platformer and I did draw a sprite on a body before but then realized that my gravity is really floaty. After googling I found out that I should work with meters when using Box2D and I changed my code to work with a pixel to meter conversion ratio of 25.

Since then I can't get everything to work though, my sprite just won't draw on my body.

Camera:

```
float width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * PIXELS_TO_METERS;
float height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * PIXELS_TO_METERS;

camera = new OrthographicCamera(width / 2, height / 2);
camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
camera.update();
```

Here is the code for my body:

```
idleRegion = new TextureRegion(xeonTexture, 20, 13, 50, 65);

xeonSprite = new Sprite(idleRegion);

    //Physics
bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(100 * PIXELS_TO_METERS, 100 * PIXELS_TO_METERS);
bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox((xeonSprite.getWidth() / 2) * PIXELS_TO_METERS, (xeonSprite.getHeight() / 2) * PIXELS_TO_METERS);

FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = 1f;
fixtureDef.friction = 1f;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0f;
fixtureDef.isSensor = false;

physicsFixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
```

Here is how I set the position of my sprite:

```
final float widthD2 = (xeonSprite.getWidth() / 2);
final float heightD2 = (xeonSprite.getHeight() / 2);
final float angle = this.getBodyAngle();

xeonSprite.setOrigin(widthD2, heightD2);
xeonSprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - xeonSprite.getWidth() / 2, body.getPosition().y - xeonSprite.getHeight() / 2);
xeonSprite.setRotation((float) Math.toRadians(angle));
```

I also tried the following:

```
xeonSprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - xeonSprite.getWidth() / 2 * METERS_TO_PIXELS, body.getPosition().y - xeonSprite.getHeight() / 2 * METERS_TO_PIXELS);
```

And here is how I draw my Sprite:

```
penguinBatch.begin();
xeon.getPenguinSprite(stateTime, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()).draw(penguinBatch);
penguinBatch.end();
```

Comment: Don't use Pixel to Meter conversation, just setup your camera right. For example, is you want to see 100 meters in x-direction on screen, your camera should have a width of 100. The camera does the pixel to meter conversation under the hood for you. An even better solution is to use `Viewport`, read the wiki for more info.

Comment: also add some trivial way to zoom out/in in huge quantities, to see, if the sprite is "somewhere/huge/microscopic" due to wrong scaling or centers not set etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another case of "Pixels do not exist in your game world", they are only there to represent you game world to your client. A camera man for TV need to know as much about your TV as you need to know about your clients screens. Just capture what you want to show and let LibGDX do the rest.

So, you should never, ever work with pixels. In the case you want pixel perfect drawing you might want to setup your camera to the amount of pixels of the screen you are targeting but after that you treat these "pixels" as units.

Box2D **does not** work with pixel per meter. It works with `1 unit == 1 meter` and you should stick to that. But how much meters a pixel should represent is still up to you.

If you want to draw a 1m x 1m box you should **not** multiply by some number you create based of screen pixels like you do now, you should just give it `1 x 1` to represent the box.

```
shape.setAsBox(1, 1);
```

Your sprite should be exactly the same

```
 xeonSprite.setSize(1, 1);
```

And you should position them on the same position. It's really that simple, `1 UNIT == 1m` and there is nothing more to it, the camera does the rest. If you want to show 9m x 16m of your game world you setup your camera like this.

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(9, 16);
```

If you want to represent the empire state building you would give the body and sprite a size of `57, 443` and then your camera needs to represent a much larger area, if you don't want to render a small portion of it. If you want to fit the height exactly on screen without stretching you need your own conversion.

```
float camHeight = 443;
float aspectRatio = Gdx.graphics.width / Gdx.graphics.height
float camWidth = aspectRatio * 443;
```

Although those `Gdx` calls give the pixels your clients are running you should still not treat these as pixels about these since you don't know at what screen I will be playing your game.

Now forget about the empire state building example and your camera's center is positioned at `0, 0` world space so bottom left is at `-4.5, -8` so you might want to translate it and don't forget to `.update` the camera. You are currently doing this in your code.

If you start drawing your sprite and updating Box2D you will see a ball drop from the center of your screen. Of course you need to keep updating your sprites position to match the body position for it to move along with the Box2D body.

Just forget pixels, unless you want to code your own camera or viewports, which you probably do not want because you chose LibGDX. The rest of your game code does not need to work with pixels in any way. The `OrthographicCamera` can calculate world position to screen position for you by `camera.unproject(touchVector)`.